# ROS msg files, generate c++ header without installing ROS?

Tags: c++, ros

I am trying to convert some c++ code to run without ROS. So far so good, but I am missing some header files. Looking into ROS and catkin, it looks like these files are generated from the msg files when you build a ROS project with catkin make.

My question is, how can I create these files without using ROS or catkin?

What do the header files look like?

The example msg file is: (KeyFrame.msg)

```
Header header
int64  frame_id
int8   command
sensor_msgs/Image img0
sensor_msgs/Image img1
int32 lm_count
std_msgs/Int64MultiArray lm_id_data
geometry_msgs/Vector3[]  lm_2d_data
geometry_msgs/Vector3[]  lm_3d_data
std_msgs/UInt8MultiArray lm_descriptor_data
geometry_msgs/Transform  T_c_w
```

Comment: This is a little confusing. Why do you want to have this code run without ros? Message files are very specific to ros so it doesn’t make a lot of sense that you want to use message headers but not ros.

Comment: The generation itself is part of the ROS client libraries. Once the header files are generated, you can use them without ROS itself. See: http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Building_.msg_Files